# Java Server Side Error message validation without actually submitting an application

Tags: testing, ui-automation

I am trying to create a testing application to validate server side error messages. Right now our framework is such that each time a incorrect value is entered in a field and the submit button is clicked and on submission, the error message displayed on  the page is captured.

Is there anyway I can bypass this technique, such that the validation happens only in the server side and is passed back to the client side, without having to reload the page each time.

Any other ideas would be much appreciated. Please try to ignore the lameness of the question :( I'm just starting off and wanted to try something new to reduce the time taken to capture the error messages.

Thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), Luke!

There are a lot of options to do this. You may use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for sending your form data to some validation servlet. Or you may use [JSF](http://www.google.com/search?q=jsf%20ajax%20validation) for it. It largely depends on your framework and/or architecture of your application.

Comment: @Luke I'm sorry to be bothering you, but could you please elaborate with some suggestions. I'm starting from scratch over here. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: There are so many ways to do, what you want. I can't elaborate all of them without information about your system.